# i18n is not working in firefox web extension after changing the browser language

Tags: internationalization, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have written a web extension plugin for firefox. I want to support i18n for that. But it does not work if I changed the language from the following option

about:preferences#content -> From language setting I have added fr -> Move UP and I restarted the browser.

After the above setting the browser locale got change but the web-extension pop-up locale didn't change.

If i change from the about:config -> general.useragent.locale and changed the locale to fr and then restarted the browser, the i18n worked for the web-extension pop-up.

So is there any way to support i18n for web-extension by changing the language from about:preferences#content option.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in Firefox. Please add a [mcve] to your question so the problem can be duplicated/verified. Check for bugs on [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/). Once you have something that can duplicate the problem, [file a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi).

Comment: WebExtension initializes some of is settings when the browser launches. In fact as of FF55, some of them are cached at installation and cant be changed. I have not tested i18n but from your post, it seems that might be too.